Did someone know how to "bake" pivot point orientation (like in maya)
i have several objects wich i have to modified, and they have diferent position and rotation (image 1)

to linked them i need to "bake" position and rotation, but set origin gave me only position
i little bit confused, but looks like blender pivot point have no rotation at all
(in maya its will be done with "bake pivot") 

Ctrl A > Apply Location/Rotation/ Scale.

I know about this function, but I need exactly the opposite action
(if i do Apply to all objects and then "link object data" they will just move to the origin
what actually need: each one have its position and rotation by the world

do you mean that you want the origin of each object to be align with the orientation of its mesh?

yep this is what i try to recieve)

If you want to align the origin of each object to its geometry (because for some reason it was misaligned) go in Edit mode, select a face and make its normal the new transform orientation:

Then in Object mode activate the Transform Affect Only Origins option:

And finally, Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation:


Thank you very much )))
it's great solution
